# Self-published news, who is the "publisher"?

Tags: google-search, schema.org, publisher

I'm trying to implement Schema.org in my news website. In [this Google guideline](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/articles) I'm following the left example with Microdata.

Everything is fine, except for one property, the `publisher`.

Given that I'm talking about the news on my own site, what am I supposed to write in the `publisher`? Do I have to write my own company?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don’t *have* to provide a `publisher`. If you don’t, you can’t get an Article rich result in Google Search for AMP HTML pages, but nothing else happens.

While Schema.org expects either an `Organization` or a `Person` item as value for [`publisher`](http://schema.org/publisher), Google requires an `Organization` item for their Article rich result ([only for AMP HTML pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43615702/1591669)). So for example, news authors that are not part of an organization can’t get the Article rich result for their AMP HTML page.

If your organization *publishes* the news, using it as value for `publisher` is appropriate.