# Publisher and Name Microdata

Tags: schema.org, microdata

In a BlogPosting or an Article if the publisher is a person how to use Schema.org and Microdata?

I could find that answer: 
[Proper way to use 'publisher' in BlogPosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43602731/proper-way-to-use-publisher-in-blogposting/43606013#43606013)

> ```html
> <div itemprop="publisher" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
>   <span itemprop="name">Some Name</span>
> </div>
> ```

But the [Google Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) says:

> The attribute publisher.itemtype has an invalid value

Perhaps I do not understand well well the answer? How to use `publisher` if it is a person or if it is the same than the author?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the correct way to provide the publisher in case it’s a person.

Unfortunately, most of the time Google’s SDTT reports something as error which isn’t an error with Schema.org/Microdata, but with Google’s requirements for getting one of their rich results.

This seems to be the case here, too: it’s likely an error for the AMP version of the [Articles rich result](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/articles#article_types), for which Google only considers organizations (and not persons) as publishers:

> **`publisher`**
>
> `Organization`; required (AMP), ignored (non-AMP)
>
> The publisher of the article.

So if the publisher is a person, simply ignore this error.

If the publisher is the same as the author, you can use both properties in the same `itemprop` attribute:

```html
<div itemprop="author publisher" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
```

Comment: When setting a value this way: `<aside class="post__author" itemprop="author publisher" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">` I get an error: `publisher.itemtype has an incorrect value`. So it looks like it's not a correct answer in this case.

Comment: @sunpietro: This is exactly what this question and answer is about, no? The error in Google’s SDTT doesn’t mean that it’s incorrect, as I explained in my answer. 1) Google only recognizes `Organization` values for `publisher`. 2) If your `publisher` is a `Person`, simply ignore the error in Google’s SDTT. Nothing else you can do.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your answer.

Comment: ([my similar answer to a Webmasters SE question about the same issue](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/110350/17633))